# How do Active Directory accounts work off network

Tags: windows, laptop, user-accounts, active-directory, ldap

When you take a laptop off the business network how does one login if you use Active Directory accounts to access the machine.

Are profiles cached after first logging in?

Answer (score 2):

Cached domain logon only works if the user has logged on once with a valid password. Windows will then store the MD5 (see comments below) hash of this password on the local disk. If the PC has no connection to an Active Directory domain controller the next time the same user logs on, Windows will authenticate the user locally using the locally stored password hash.

By default, Windows stores the password hashes of the last 10 logons. Thus, if multiple users share a PC, it is possible that the cached domain logon fails even though the user has logged on this machine before.

Comment: Because a lot of people seem to misunderstand this (IMO), I'd like to add some additional info: the `Interactive logon: Number of previous logons to cache` setting determines the number of unique user logons to cache. So it's about logon `entities`, not logon `instances`, which is what I think a lot of people think this setting is about. A single unique cached logon (entity) can logon an unlimited number of times `off network` as long as that unique logon remains cached.

Comment: An addition about "profiles cached": yes, when a user logs in for the first time (and connects to the domain controller) the profile is created and stored on the PC.